# Python Scrapy - Guardar log en dos archivos log diferentes

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

tengo una duda la cual no logro comprender ¿Como puedo lograr `loggear` info en un archivo log en especifico.

He creado una clase donde creo dos logs:

- uno para obtener la info en general
- otro para los puros errrores

En el primer achivo lo que hago es que vaya agregando toda la info que hace el debug de scrapy. Y si tiene algun error, he creado un segundo archivo donde va agregando todos los errores. Sin embargo, me nacio un detalle.

Agrega los errores, sin embargo, si quiero saber en que url se esta ejecutando, esto tambien lo quiero loggear en el archivo de errores (aunque esto no sea un error, necesito saber para ver a que errores 'pertenece')

Es decir, tener algo asi en el log de errors:

```
[2024-03-08 12:03:44,419 [INFO] Estamos ejecutando: https://www.doctoralia.com.mx/jose-alfredo-valdovinos-estrada/angiologo/morelia
[2024-03-08 12:03:44,419] [ERROR] [Error][GeneralData] Doctor online status blank or failed False
[2024-03-08 12:04:11,211] [ERROR] [Error][ServesTo] Doctor serves to second part blank or failed <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6ee1c3d968ae02036470b2b4c88c63cf", element="CF5C1C8D5F8E0854A3957A5619FA029F_element_309")>
```

El problema es que no he logrado hacer esto ultimo, el agregar esta linea:

```
[2024-03-08 12:03:44,419 [INFO] Estamos ejecutando: https://www.doctoralia.com.mx/jose-alfredo-valdovinos-estrada/angiologo/morelia
```

al logger de errors.

Ahora un poco de contexto con mi codigo:

Esta info la obtengo de un archivo `.env` la propiedad se llama:

```
LOG_CUSTOM=doctoralia_errors
```

Esta es mi clase:

```
    def configure_log():
        FormatLog.log_for_general_info()
        FormatLog.log_for_errors()

    def log_for_general_info():
        logging.basicConfig(format="[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s", filename="doctoralia.log", level=logging.INFO)

    def log_for_errors():
        # Creamos un logger
        error_logger = logging.getLogger("doctoralia_errors")
        error_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # Creamos un manejador para la consola
        error_file_handler = logging.FileHandler("doctoralia_errors.log")
        error_file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # Definimos el formato del mensaje de registro
        formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s")
        error_file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        # Añadimos el manejador de archivo al logger de errores
        error_logger.addHandler(error_file_handler)

        # Si deseas que los mensajes de errores también se impriman en la consola, puedes añadir un StreamHandler
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        error_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Aqui esta el metodo donde cargo esto:

```
def load_custom_log():
        dotenv.load_dotenv()
        custom_error_log = os.environ['LOG_CUSTOM']
        return custom_error_log
```

una vez ya modificado esto, lo mando a llamar en mi spider, el cual en el init cargo el `configure_log()` quedando de la siguiente manera:

Mi spider

```
class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    allowed_domains = ["www.doctoralia.com.mx"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.doctoralia.com.mx/"]

    def start_requests(self):
            yield SeleniumRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], wait_time=12, callback=self.parse, meta={"need_filters": need_filters})

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        # Aqui debe ir el componente de logging creado para este spider
        FormatLog.configure_log()

    def parse(self, response):
      while True:
        try:
          # Comienza el scrapeo de los datos
          list_doctor_final = self.scrap_doctors(driver)
          if list_doctor_final:
            for doctor in list_doctor_final:
                yield doctor

          next_button.click()
        except Exception as e:
          logging.getLogger(Constants.load_custom_log()).error("[Error][DoctoraliaSpider]Failed pagination on position %d or parse %s", count_pag, e)
          break


    def scrap_doctors(self, driver):
            for doctor_item in doctors_cards:
            try:
                profile_url_xpath = ".//h3//a"
                profile_url = doctor_item.find_element(By.XPATH, profile_url_xpath)
                if profile_url:
                    new_url = profile_url.get_attribute("href")
                    print("Estamos ejecutando:", new_url)
                    logging.getLogger(Constants.load_custom_log()).info("[URL][GeneralData] URL Execute  %s on pagination position [%d]", new_url, count_pag)
            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                logging.getLogger(Constants.load_custom_log()).error("[Error][DoctoraliaSpider] Failed, url or item not working %s", e)
                continue

            except Exception as e:
                logging.getLogger(Constants.load_custom_log()).error("[Error][URL][DoctoraliaSpider] URL Failed on pagination position [%d] %s", count_pag, new_url)
                logging.getLogger(Constants.load_custom_log()).error("[Error][DoctoraliaSpider] Failed, url or item not working %s", e)
                continue
```